# OSX El Capitan Apache Forbidden when excluding ~username from URL

Tags: macos, apache

I'm trying to set up my Mac as a web server as a leaning experience; everything is working perfectly except one small thing.

If I go to here, it works:

http://mywebsite.ddns.net/~username/

If I go here (without `~username`), I get error message "You don't have permission to access / on this server":

http://mywebsite.ddns.net/

I'm guessing it has something to do with my `httpd.conf` or `username.conf` settings. I've adjusted them as recommended from other answers but I'm still getting errors, here are the relevant settings from each:

**httpd.conf:**

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/username/Sites"
<Directory "/Library/Users/username/Sites">
```

**username.conf:**

```
<Directory "/Users/username/Sites/">
AllowOverride All
Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Are there any other settings i should be looking at, or perhaps the Sites folder itself has incorrect permissions? Here are the folder:

```
drwxr-xr-x  40 username  staff  1360 27 Mar 19:24 Sites
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using the `apache` that comes with OSX, then that *should* work out-of-the-box I believe (I don't remember editing the config to get it working).  You need to find the log file to see what the issue is (this is always the place to go to when diagnosing server issues).

Comment: Have you tried `/Users/yourUsername` rather than a tilde?

Comment: OK, just looked at my `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and the user-dir settings are commented out: `#Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-userdir.conf`. That contains the user-related settings.